# getting undefined reference `__locale_ctype_ptr' and `__getreent' when using /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32 on Cygwin64

Tags: compiler-errors, cygwin, mingw32, cygwin-64

I am trying to build project on Cygwin64 using x86_64-w64-mingw32

Added compiler in CMakeList.txt:
**set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)**

but getting below mentioned undefined reference while doing make

**/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/test/myprogram.o:myprogram.c:(.text+0x76): **undefined reference to `__locale_ctype_ptr'** /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/test/myprogram.o:myprogram.c:(.text+0x38d): **undefined reference to` __getreent'****

please suggest how can i resolve above error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the command before the error ?

Comment: the most likely cause is that you are mixing cygwin and mingw libraries in the build. While ` grep -H getreent *.a` produces a lot of output in `/usr/lib/` it returns empty when run in `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/`